# VF and Apex: Save data to Staging Object Pending Approval

Tags: apex, visualforce

Every step is a learning process for me.  I've gotten as far as extracting the data from the Master object onto a VF page for the users to edit and then do an upsert statement to save the updated records back to the Master Object.

What I would like to do is to save the updated records to a Staging object and await there for approval.  The staging object is identical in field names to the Master object.  How can I redirect the save to the staging object instead of the Master object?  Thanks

Controller:

```
public class ControllerPartsUpdate {

    public String OPN_v{get;set;}
    public String BU_v{get;set;}
    public String Root_v{get;set;}
 
    // wrapper classes for the Master being managed
    public List<MasterKey1Wrapper> MasterWrappers {get; set;}
    // the unique record key master value (Design Activities)
    public Integer mainKey {get; set;}

    public List<SelectOption> GetOPNOptions(){
    
    // You could populate this using a query for accounts
        List<SelectOption> OPNOptions = new List<SelectOption>{
            new SelectOption('Part1', 'Part1'),
           
        };
        
        return OPNOptions;
    }
    
    public List<SelectOption> GetBUOptions(){
    // You could populate this using a query for accounts
        List<SelectOption> BUOptions = new List<SelectOption>{
            new SelectOption('BU1', 'BU1'),
        };
    
        return BUOptions;
    }
    
    public List<SelectOption> GetRootPartOptions(){
    // You could populate this using a query for accounts
        List<SelectOption> RootPartOptions = new List<SelectOption>{
            new SelectOption('RootPart1', 'RootPart1')
        };
    
        return RootPartOptions;
    }

    public Void GO()
    {
        mainKey=1;
        Masterwrappers=new List<MasterKey1Wrapper>();
        
        
        List<Catalog_Master__c> Master_Data=[select Name, Business_Unit__c,         Root_Part_Number__c  from Catalog_Master__c Where Name =:OPN_v and  Business_Unit__c=:BU_v and  Root_Part_Number__c=:Root_v Limit 5];
        for (Catalog_Master__c Master : Master_Data)
        {
            Masterwrappers.add(new MasterKey1Wrapper(mainKey++, Master));
        }   

    }
    
    // save the users changes (Stagging)
    public PageReference SaveMaster()
    {
        PageReference resultMaster=null;
        Boolean errorMaster=false;
        List<Catalog_Master__c> toUpsertMaster=new List<Catalog_Master__c>();
   
        for (MasterKey1Wrapper Masterwrapper : MasterWrappers)
        {
 
                if (String.valueof(Masterwrapper.Master.Name) == Null)
                    MasterWrapper.Master.Name.addError('Required');

                    toUpsertMaster.add(Masterwrapper.Master);

        }
        
        if (!ApexPages.hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.Error))
        {
            
            upsert toUpsertMaster;
        
        }
        
        return resultMaster;
    } 

}
```

Wrapper Class:

```
public With Sharing class MasterKey1Wrapper
{    
   Public Integer Key1{get;set;}
   Public Catalog_Master__c Master{get;set;}

   Public MasterKey1Wrapper(Integer inKey1, Catalog_Master__c inMaster)
   {
    Key1=inKey1;
    Master=inMaster;
   }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="ControllerPartsUpdate">

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Catalog Update Module" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Selections" columns="3">                
            <apex:selectList value="{!OPN_v}" label="OPN" required="True">
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!OPNOptions}"/>
            </apex:selectList>                
            <apex:selectList value="{!BU_v}" Label="Business Unit" required="true">
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!BUOptions}"/>
            </apex:selectList>                
            <apex:selectList value="{!Root_v}" Label="Root Part" required="true">
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!RootPartOptions}"/>
            </apex:selectList>               
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>  

    <apex:commandButton value="Go!" action="{!Go}" rerender="out" status="status"/>

     <apex:pageBlock title="Catalog" mode="edit" id="out">
        <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Your Outputs">
            
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MasterWrappers}" var="MasterWrap">
                <apex:column style="width:10%" headerValue="">
                  <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!MasterWrap.selected}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column style="width:25%" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputText styleclass="requiredHeader" value="{!$ObjectType.Catalog_Master__c.fields.Name.label}" />
                  </apex:facet>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!MasterWrap.Master.Name}" required="false" />
                </apex:column>                    
                <apex:column style="width:25%" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputText styleclass="requiredHeader" value="{!$ObjectType.Catalog_Master__c.fields.Business_Unit__c.label}" />
                  </apex:facet>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!MasterWrap.Master.Business_Unit__c}" required="false" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column style="width:25%" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputText styleclass="requiredHeader" value="{!$ObjectType.Catalog_Master__c.fields.Root_Part_Number__c.label}" />
                  </apex:facet>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!MasterWrap.Master.Root_Part_Number__c}" required="false" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveMaster}" rerender="Out"/> 

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

</apex:page>

Comment: Why do you need to save a copy of the record pending approval? Do you need both original and changed data values? If you don't, I would suggest you just status the record differently while it is pending approval, if you need it to be "read only" you could even add a record type and new page layout with all readonly fields.

Comment: Thanks @JimRae.  I thought your suggestion was great but yes I do need before and after values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a record in the staging object and I am assuming you want to set it for approval once the record is created and relate it to the master.

To Do : In your `savemaster(`) method where you `upsert toUpsertMaster`; check if this upsert went through by `changing upsert toUpsertMaster;` to `Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(toUpsertMaster);`

```
List<staging__c> stagerecordstoinsert = new List<staging__c>();
Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(toUpsertMaster);
for (Database.UpsertResult res : results) {
            if (res.isSuccess()) {
                if (res.isCreated()) {
```

> ```
>                    // create your staging record
>                         staging__c stage = new staging__c(
>                         **Id** = res.getId());
>                         stagerecordstoinsert.add(stage);
> ```

```
                } else {
                    System.debug('Updated record ID ' + res.getId() + '.');
                }
            }
            else {
                if (res.getErrors().size() > 0) {
                    System.debug(res.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
                }
            }
        } //outside the upserresult for loop.

        database.saveresult**[]** SR = database.insert(stagerecordstoinsert );
```

Comment: Thanks @Rao, I'll look thru your codes and see if I can incorporate this int mine.

Comment: HI @Rao, I only need the section where you save the updated data into the staging object.  I don't think this method works because you are taking the ID from the master object and inserting it into the staging object.  Any further help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With assistance from others, I was able to find a solution that will work.

1. Extract data from the Master object
2. Create a temporary object of Staging object type
3. migrate the data from Master to temporary object
4. temporary object will be the data source to the VF page
5. once saved data from VF page will be saved to staging object.

Code:

```
public Void GO()
{
    mainKey=1;        
    stagingwrappers=new List<StagingKey1Wrapper>();

    List<Impact_Catalog_Master__c> Master_Data=[select ID, Business_Unit__c,    Root_Part_Number__c  from Master__c Limit 5];
    for (Master__c Master : Master_Data)
    {
        staging__c staging_obj = new staging__c();
        staging_obj.Business_Unit__c= Master.Business_Unit__c;
        staging_obj.Root_Part__c = Master.Root_Part_Number__c;

        Stagingwrappers.add(new StagingKey1Wrapper(mainKey++, staging_obj));
    }          
}

/ save the users changes (Stagging)
public PageReference SaveStaging()
{
    PageReference resultStaging=null;
    Boolean errorStaging=false;
    List<staging__c> toUpsertStaging=new List<staging__c>();
    for (StagingKey1Wrapper stagingwrapper : StagingWrappers)
    {

            if (String.valueof(stagingwrapper.Staging.PartNO__c) == Null)
                stagingwrapper.Staging.Name.addError('Required');

                toUpsertStaging.add(stagingwrapper.Staging);

    }
    upsert toUpsertStaging;         
    return resultstaging;
}
```

Comment: Caky - please mark as a solution

Comment: @Caky - mark this post as the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can do it as below:

```
List<Impact_Catalog_Master__c> Master_Data=[SELECT ID, Business_Unit__c,Root_Part_Number__c  
                                                FROM Master__c Limit 5];
 List<staging_obj> stagingRecordList = (List<staging_obj>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(Master_Data),Type.forName('List<Impact_Catalog_Master__c>'));
```

After this you can perform any business logic on this list and just upsert it.

Hope this will help

Thanks